# In-app purchase for windows phone html5 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm having some problems locating any resource, implementation or tutorial on this topic. I've got a app i've created in phonegap and now I want to enable in-app purchases.

I've taken a look at a plain HTML5 app for windows phone, but I can't figure out the references. It only includes a bundle called `Windows Phone` and `.Net for Windows Phone`.

I've found [this sample for Windows 8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a/view/SourceCode#content), but again the references is a mist.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206950(v=vs.105).aspx

Basically you might reference Windows.ApplicationModel.Store